# Issue with calculating number of steps to be in final image

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, slider

I want to calculate Steps to be in final image using jQuery-UI slider , my solution was to put a counter (i) and initialize it to get the number of steps, but my problem is when I slide from right to left,the counter still increments the value.
I want to know which event I can use to decrement the counter, when I want to slide from right to left, for going to the first value.

Example :

We have 4 images :

1) I click in the second image

2) the counter "i" is initialized to 0

3) I slide from left to right, no problem, I have 1->2

4) 2 steps to be in final image

5) When I slide from the last image to the first (from right to left)

### Expected Result

5) I should have 2->1

### obtained result

5) i have 3->4

### This is my code :

### HTML Code :

```
<h1>Step to be in final image : </h1>
<div id="slider"></div>

<p>Step to be in final image : <span id="slider-value"></span> steps</p>
<input type=hidden name=value value="">
 <ul class="teintestyle">
<li>
 <img border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/81/" width="100" height="81" alt="1" />
</li>

<li>
<img border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" width="100" height="81" alt="2" />
</li>

<li>
<img border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" width="100" height="81" alt="3" />
</li>
<li>
<img border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text" width="100" height="81" alt="4" />

</li>
</ul>
```

### Js Code:

```
var i=0;
var value2;
$('.teintestyle li').click(function(){
    i=0;
    var value = $(this).index();
    $('#slider-value').text(i);
    $('#slider').slider('value', (value+1));
    value2 = $(this).index();

});

$("#slider").slider(
{
    min: 1,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {


        if(value2==ui.value)
        {

            return false;
        }
        else
        {

            i++;
            $( "#slider-value" ).html(i);
        }
    }
}

);
```

jsfiddle :

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2952/)

Answer (score 1):

Is that you looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.teintestyle li').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).index();
    $('#slider-value').text(value);
    $('#slider').slider('value', (value));
    $('.teintestyle  li  img').css('border','none');
    $('.teintestyle > li').eq(value).find('img').css('border','20px solid red');
});

$("#slider").slider(
{
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#slider-value').text(ui.value);
        $('.teintestyle  li  img').css('border','none');
    $('.teintestyle > li').eq(ui.value).find('img').css('border','20px solid red');
    }
}
);

    });
```

[**DEMO Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2953/)

Comment: it's not what i am looking for what i am looking for is : when I click to second image i should have 0 step not 1 because i didn't start to slide so i should have 0 -> 1 -> 2 not 1->2->3 and the third image i should have 0->1 not 2->3 do you see what i mean ?

Comment: @JohnLow .. sorry for that but  I can't get your point ..   you can play around the value and ui.value  may be increase it by 1 or decrease by 1 .. but if as you say the 1st image will be -1 :(

Comment: @Mohammed can you see my new code that what i want but its to long can you minimize it ?

Comment: can you see my last demo, you will understand all

Comment: @JohnLow .. but just try to click on last image .. I think you have a problem there

Comment: no its normal because the last image is the final image we can't calculate steps there because we are in final image we have 0 steps

Comment: can you see my final code its great now, can you look and give me your opinion thank you so mush !